# String from ArrayList to use as key in HashMap?

Tags: java, collections

I have an `ArrayList<String>`, the strings of which I'm using as keys in a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>`

When I finally put the keys and values in my `HashMap`, I don't actually know where a particular string ended up going, i.e. what index position in my `ArrayList<String>` (because the strings only get added depending on certain conditions)

I know which string each `put` should use as the key, but I don't know how to grab hold of it from the `ArrayList<String>` since I don't know where it is.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, in terms of what you're actually trying to achieve. Please clarify it.

Comment: your question is very unclear. at least post some code.

Comment: How do you know which string to use as the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrays have an indexOf method, to which you can pass your string to find the index.

But if you know which String to put in the Map, why do you need the list of keys, or why do you need to get the String out the list, since you have it already?

Answer (score 1):

In short, if you want to maintain hashing and also the order of insertion, then look at `java.util.LinkedHashMap`